# 辞書内の値を合わせたい

Tags: python

実現したいこと
以下の対象辞書イメージのkey（Data_x[xx]）で[xx]の数字が同じ場合、そのvalueを合成後、新しい辞書を作成したいです

対象辞書イメージ

```
Test=
{'Data_1[1]': 'test','Data_1[2]': 'call','Data_1[5]': 'pkup','Data_2[1]': 'direct','Data_2[5]': 'all','Data_3[2]': 'direct','Data_3[5]': 'all',}
```

※ 例[1]の場合

```
'Data_1[1]': 'test'
'Data_2[1]': 'direct'
⇒'FData_1':'test direct'
```

最終結果イメージ

```
FTest ={'FData_1':'test direct','FData_2':'call direct','FData_5':'pkup all all'}
```

何卒よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
import re

Test = {
  'Data_1[1]': 'test', 'Data_1[2]': 'call',
  'Data_1[5]': 'pkup', 'Data_2[1]': 'direct',
  'Data_2[5]': 'all',  'Data_3[2]': 'direct',
  'Data_3[5]': 'all',
}

FTest = {}
for k, v in Test.items():
    idx = 'FData_' + re.findall(r'\[(\d+)\]', k)[0]
    if idx not in FTest:
        FTest[idx] = v
    else:
        FTest[idx] += ' ' + v

print(FTest)

#
{'FData_1': 'test direct', 'FData_2': 'call direct', 'FData_5': 'pkup all all'}
```

Comment: いつも本当にありがとうございます！！確認させて頂きます

Comment: うまく想定通りの動きが出来ました！
教えて頂いたソースについて勉強させて頂きます！